# How do I copy last column value of an excel sheet to another Excel sheet's last column using asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, spire.xls

[This is the screenshot of the last column in an Excel sheet that I want to copy to another Excel sheet last column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmYWq.png)

May I know how to do it using asp.net c# code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **sheet.Copy()** to copy a range from an excel sheet to another excel sheet.

```
Workbook workbook1 = new Workbook();
workbook1.LoadFromFile("file1.xlsx");
Worksheet sheet1 = workbook1.Worksheets[0];

Workbook workbook2 = new Workbook();
workbook2.LoadFromFile("file2.xlsx");
Worksheet sheet2 = workbook2.Worksheets[0];

//copy the last column of sheet1 and insert after the last column of sheet2
sheet2.Copy(sheet1.Range[sheet1.FirstRow, sheet1.LastColumn, sheet1.LastRow, sheet1.LastColumn], sheet2.Range[sheet2.FirstRow, sheet2.LastColumn + 1, sheet2.LastRow, sheet2.LastColumn + 1], true);

workbook2.SaveToFile("copy.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2013);
```